# I cant connect to the database through the microsoft login by using code in nuget console code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, model-view-controller

I am trying to connect the database file for web application. i put the code in Nuget console to connect the database but my microsoft account can't get it as login fails. What is the reason behind the failure of login?

Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console, type the following command:

PM> Scaffold-DbContext "server=alpha;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;database=StDb2Sql;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
PM>

After executing some files I received message:
Cannot open database "StDb2Sql" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\kartikpatel2188@gmail.com'.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you've prefixed it with a Domain: <strike>MicrosoftAccount\</strike>
kartikpatel2188@gmail.com

Use your email: `kartikpatel2188@gmail.com`

Comment: Actually I am getting: Error number 4060, State 1, Class 11 Cannot open database "XYZEveDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\kartikpatel2188@gmail.com'.

Comment: The error message still states you're using the wrong domain. Good luck!